# SSRS - Conditional location

Tags: reporting-services, location, conditional-statements

Using SSRS 2012 against SQL Server 2008 R2. Is there a way to conditionally specify the location of a rectangle or tablix object?

I work in education and have a report showing various data contained in a number of rectangle objects. To keep the report as tidy as possible, I'd like to specify the position of a rectangle containing exam results, based on the number of exams the pupil has sat - the fewer exams, the further to the right in the report body the object will sit.

Thanks,
 Gavin

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to conditionally set Location (`top` and `left` properties) of a Tablix or Rectangle item. But you can use `padding` property for conditionally space tablix and textbox items.